# Detecting if an input string contains html c#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have looked up this topic online and found some answers but no success yet with my problem,
I have this method implemented:

```
public bool ContainsHtml(string input)
{
    bool containsHtml = (input != HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input));
    return containsHtml;
}
```

So this method will return true if I test a string which contains any html tag, but the problem is that if the string I am testing is

```
"3>5"
```

it will still return true because the string contains ">" sign, and I don't want that because I only want to detect if string contains html.

I have used this regex too, but again the same problem occured:

```
public bool ContainsHtml(string input)
{
    Regex containsHtmlRegex = new Regex(@"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>");
    bool containsHtml = containsHtmlRegex .IsMatch(input);
    return containsHtml;
}
```

If some one can please help me out, I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The term "contains HTML" is basically meaningless.  What if it's just talking about HTML tags? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Well, in your first example, once you HTML-encode something it *by definition* is HTML...

Comment: @SLaks I am implementing OWASP in one of my projects and I do not want to allow any html in any request, so I need this method to recognize if a sting contains html in it.

Comment: @Nia: Not allowing HTML doesn't really make sense.  You should instead always escape text.

Comment: @Nia that is a solved problem - don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Jamiec I have been looking at this problem for 2 days now, and nothing worked, so thats why I posted it here.I am hoping that may be I can get some good advice here.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for your answer,sorry i did not get the part about "eacaping text", what do you mean by escaping text?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content

Comment: @SLaks Thank you, I will look at it, The problem in that I do have checks at the front end of my project, so it will not allow html or any script but now few clients use the services directly, so there my front end can not protect , so thats why I was thinking of implementing some method which will protect the request input fields from any html.

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong.  Users can legitimately use `<` and `&` characters.  You **need** to properly escape all user input when concatenated into HTML or other formats.

Comment: Try looking at the [HTML Sanitizer project](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)!

Comment: I think this question is worth a good answer.  Hackers are notoriously persistent so even fields that are not supposed to contain HTML could be abused later.  All it takes is one simple mistake as a web developer and your system could be hacked.  One way to avoid the problem is to disallow anything that looks like HTML in a field.  So the question is how much is too much...   I think this would be part of a defense in depth answer.